# How to dump data into Json file using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

**How to dump data into Json file**
*as can see in the below python code I am trying the dump data in Json file so but I am struggling to do it in python  code *

```
import time
import json
import os


def long_function(name):
    cache_path = 'cache.json'
    if not os.path.isfile(cache_path):
        with open(cache_path, 't') as json_file:
            cache_file_data = [name]
            jsondump(cache_file_data, json_file)
    else:
        with open(cache_path, 'r') as json_file:
            cache_file_data = json.load(json_file)

    if name in cache_file_data:
        print("Name already exist")
        return name
    else:
        cache_file_data.append(name)
        for e in range(5):
            time.sleep(1)
            print(e+1)
        with open(cache_path, 'w') as json_file:
            jsondump(cache_file_data, json_file)
            print("New Name added in cache")
            return name


print(long_function('nitu'))
```

*so please resolve my problem......please help me*

Comment: There is no such open mode as `'t'`.  You either want `'w'` to write, or `'r'` to read the file.  Also, the function you want is `json.dump`, not `jsondump`.  Why are you sleeping for 5 seconds?  That will irritate your users.

Comment: @TimRoberts Mode `'t'` does exist. It's even the default. Did you maybe look at the documentation for Python 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nothing but follow this pattern and your so your code error is ..you are not defined file mode correctly in if condition

```
with open (cache_path. "t") as json_file:
```

Instead of

```
with open (cache_path. "w") as json_file:
```

And second thing is you are not doing dump data

Comment: He TRIED to dump the data.  Tell him how to fix it.  That's what an answer does.

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
  
# JSON data:
x =  '{ "organization":"New_holn",
        "city":"Noida",
        "country":"India"}'
 
# python object to be appended
y = {"pin":117845}
 
# parsing JSON string:
z = json.loads(x)
  
# appending the data
z.update(y)
 
# the result is a JSON string:
print(json.dumps(z))
```